# Assign second role to user

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

I am trying to grammatically assign second 'seller' to user when the Woocommerce transaction is completed. I know that:

```
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'seller' ) );
```

will change the role but how about adding the new one to existing serialized array. What I need in wp_capabilities is `a:2:{s:7:"partner";b:1;s:6:"seller";b:1;}`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you first fetch a **WP_User object** with `get_userdata()`, you should then be able to add your additional role with the [`add_role()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_role/), like so:

```
$user = get_userdata($user_id);
$user->add_role('partner');
```